# Convert a Forsyth-Edwards Notation string to ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, chess

In chess, [Forsyth-Edwards Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation), more commonly called "FEN", is a textual way of transcribing boards. It describes each of the board's eight rows (called "ranks" in chess) from top to bottom from White's perspective. The pieces are written as K (king), Q (queen), R (rook), B (bishop), N (knight), and P (pawn). Black pieces use these letters in lowercase, and white pieces use these letters in uppercase. Empty spaces are indicated by a number from 1 to 8 indicating how many consecutive empty spaces there are. A completely empty rank would be `8`, a single black rook in the rightmost column (called "files" in chess) would be `7r`, and two white pawns on each end of a row would be `PP4PP`. Ranks are separated by a `/`. There is normally other information added, indicating which side is to move, castling and *en passant* rights, move number, and halfmove clock, but we will ignore them for the purposes of this challenge.

## Input

A FEN string, from the command line or STDIN, as you please. You may assume that this string is always valid.

## Output

Write to STDOUT a simple ASCII art representation of the board as it would actually appear:

- Pieces are represented by their character in FEN
- Empty squares are represented by spaces
- Pieces and squares are separated by a pipe `|` and there are pipes on each side of the board

So an empty board, written as `8/8/8/8/8/8/8/8` in FEN, would appear as

```
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
```

The starting position of a chess game is written as `rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR`, and would appear as

```
|r|n|b|q|k|b|n|r|
|p|p|p|p|p|p|p|p|
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | |
|P|P|P|P|P|P|P|P|
|R|N|B|Q|K|B|N|R|
```

The final position of [Anderssen-Kieseritzky 1851](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1018910), called "The Immortal Game" in the chess community, is written as `r1bk3r/p2pBpNp/n4n2/1p1NP2P/6P1/3P4/P1P1K3/q5b1`, and your program when fed that input would output:

```
|r| |b|k| | | |r|
|p| | |p|B|p|N|p|
|n| | | | |n| | |
| |p| |N|P| | |P|
| | | | | | |P| |
| | | |P| | | | |
|P| |P| |K| | | |
|q| | | | | |b| |
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to write a function which takes input and returns output, rather than writing it to STDOUT?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes By default we allow it and indeed several solutions do that already. Ultimately it's up to the OP though it seems unnecessary to override our defaults in this case.

Comment: The answer you accepted is not the shortest one. Regardless of your feelings towards golfing languages, code golf means that *the shortest code* wins.

Comment: @Dennis If I [cannot exclude golfing languages from the challenge outright](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges), I will exclude them from the winner's circle. Users may vote for the golfing language winner as they please and scroll down to see it.

Comment: You also cannot [penalize them](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7474) or [accept an arbitrary answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8707). The whole site is built around *objective* winning criteria.

Comment: @Dennis I have removed my votes from all answers from which I could remove them and removed the accept of the Perl answer. I will not, however, accept an answer to this question unless that is also required.

Comment: No, that's not required. Many challenges do not have accepted answers.

Comment: `+1` for an interesting challenge. `-2` for accepting the wrong answer for [no good reason](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9399/a-proposal-to-remove-code-golf-from-the-name-of-the-site#comment27890_9399)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Perl, 28 bytes

Includes +2 for `-lp`

Give input on STDIN

```
fen.pl <<< "r1bk3r/p2pBpNp/n4n2/1p1NP2P/6P1/3P4/P1P1K3/q5b1"
```

`fen.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -lp
s/\d/$"x$&/eg;s/|/|/g;y;/;
```

Actually in the league of some golfing languages...

Notice that the file based version needs the final newline in the file so that one is really 29 bytes. But the commandline version doesn't need that extra newline and therefore the code counts as 28 bytes:

```
perl -lpe 's/\d/$"x$&/eg;s/|/|/g;y;/;' <<< "r1bk3r/p2pBpNp/n4n2/1p1NP2P/6P1/3P4/P1P1K3/q5b1"
```

Comment: Missing shebang?

Answer (score 16):

## Retina, 13 bytes

```
\d
$* 
/
¶

|
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQKJCogCi8KwrYKCnw&input=cjFiazNyL3AycEJwTnAvbjRuMi8xcDFOUDJQLzZQMS8zUDQvUDFQMUszL3E1YjE)

### Explanation

The first part (note the trailing space):

```
\d
$*
```

is to convert a to the specific number of spaces. Retina has a `$*` feature to repeat. The way it works is: `<num>$*<char>` if there is no `<num>`, Retina will assume `$&` or the matched string, in this case the matched number.

The next part:

```
/
¶
```

is pretty simple, it replaces all `/` with `¶` which is a newline.

The last part works the same:

```
    
|
```

This will replace everything (hence why there is nothing on the first line) with `|`. Putting a `|` everywhere.

Comment: You can even do it all in ASCII for the same byte count with `S\`/` as the second stage.

Answer (score 12):

### Ruby - <s>75</s> <s>82</s> <s>78</s> <s>76</s> <s>75</s> <s>62</s> <s>59</s> <s>58</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```
->n{"|#{n.gsub(/\d|
/){' '*$&.hex}.chars*?|}|".tr'/',$/}
```

*Saved a few bytes thanks to Ventero*

Let me explain (with `\n` replacing the literal newline):

```
->n{"...".tr'/',$/}
```

This implicitly returns the value of the string, with each `/` replaced with a newline (by default, `$/` contains a newline)

```
"|#{...}|"
```

This is super simple; it's just a string containing a pipe, string interpolation, and another pipe. The string interpolation is evaluated

```
n.gsub(/\d|\n/){' '*$&.hex}...
```

This replaces every number with that many spaces. I can save a few bytes by also finding newlines here; because `hex` returns 0 if the string isn't a valid number, when it finds a newline –- i.e. the one at the end of the result of `gets` –- it replaces it with a 0-length string, effectively deleting it. Without this, there would be a trailing pipe.

`$&` is a magic variable which represents the complete text of the latest variable match, which lets me save a byte by eliminating `|d|`. I can save another byte by using `.hex` instead of `.to_i`, which works because every number is less than 9, which means that hex and decimal have the same values.

```
.chars*?|
```

This puts a pipe between every character. Note that this is what puts the pipes on either side of the lines (except the first and last) because the slashes, which eventually turn into newlines through `tr`, count as characters, and are therefore surrounded by pipes. The `?|` just means "the one-character string `"|"`".

And... that's it. It's a frankly scandalously simple program. It just uses a lot of sneaky syntax tricks.

Comment: You can save 4 more characters by applying a few simple tricks: `puts"|#{gets.gsub(/\d|\n/){' '*$&.hex}.chars*?|}|".split'/'` (of course, replace the `\n` with a literal newline again).

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth - <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
.i*\|72jcu:G`H*Hd9z\/
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.i%2a%5C%7C72jcu%3AG%60H%2aHd9z%5C%2F&input=rnbqkbnr%2Fpppppppp%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F8%2FPPPPPPPP%2FRNBQKBNR&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=8%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F8%0Arnbqkbnr%2Fpppppppp%2F8%2F8%2F8%2F8%2FPPPPPPPP%2FRNBQKBNR%0Ar1bk3r%2Fp2pBpNp%2Fn4n2%2F1p1NP2P%2F6P1%2F3P4%2FP1P1K3%2Fq5b1&debug=0).

```
+                     Concatenate
 K\|                  Store "|" in K and use value
+         K           Concatenate to end
 jK                   Join string by K, this puts "|" between each char
  :                   String substitution
        \/            Replace "/"
         b            With newline
   u                  Reduce
        9             Over [0, 9)
         z            With input as base case
    :G                String substitution current val
     `H               Replace stringifyed int from list we're looping through
     *Hd              With " "*that int
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES7, <s>80</s> 70 bytes

Is an anonymous function that accepts a string as input.

```
a=>[,...[+t?" ".repeat(t):t<"0"?`
`:t for(t of a)].join``,`
`].join`|`
```

80-byte ES6-only appraoch.

```
a=>a.split`/`.map(x=>[,...x.replace(/\d/g,t=>" ".repeat(t)),`
`].join`|`).join``
```

### Explanation

We use an array comprehension to loop over the list:

```
[+t?" ".repeat(t):t<"0"?`
`:t for(t of a)]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
[!isNaN(parseInt(t, 10)) ? " ".repeat(parseInt(t, 10)) : t === "/" ? "\n" : t for(t of a)]
```

If it's a number, we have that number of spaces. If it's a `/`, we have a newline. Otherwise, we have the character. Then, we join the comprehension with nothing to make a string.

Then, we create an array of length 3 `[,...that,"\n"]`. `...` splats the joined comprehension into chars. Joining this yields the result.

Comment: Don't you mean ES6? ES7 isn't out yet I believe.

Comment: @ericw31415 It isn't out, you're correct, but some browsers have started implementing part of the ES7 spec.

Comment: Oh OK. But still your code doesn't use any of the ES7 features, right?

Comment: @ericw31415 Actually, it does. Array comprehensions (`[x for(x of a)]`) are ES7.

Comment: Weren't Array Comprehensions removed from the spec, MDN [says they were](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions)

Comment: @SpeedyNinja At the bottom it appears to be that they are still planned forbES7, though this current version of compressions is being deprecated in favor of the `for of ` before the expression. *shudders*

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 23 bytes

```
VT=:Q`N*dN;jc.i*\|72Q\/
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VT%3D%3AQ%60N*dN%3Bjc.i*%5C|72Q%5C%2F&input=%22r1bk3r%2Fp2pBpNp%2Fn4n2%2F1p1NP2P%2F6P1%2F3P4%2FP1P1K3%2Fq5b1%22&debug=0)

How it works:

```
VT=:Q`N*dN;jc.i*\|72Q\/
VT        ;                for N in range(10):
  =:Q`N*dN                     Q = Q.replace(`N`,repeat(' ',N))
             .i*\|72Q      temp = interweave(repeat('|',72), Q)
            c        \/    temp = chop(temp,'/')
           j               temp = join(temp,'\n')
                           print temp
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 62 bytes

```
s->split("|"join(replace(s,r"\d",d->" "^parse(d)),"|")"|","/")
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a string and returns an array of strings. To call it, assign it to a variable.

The approach is the same as in QPaysTaxes' clever Ruby [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78331/20469). We replace each digit in the input with that many spaces, place `|` between each character, tack `|` onto the front and back, and split into an array on `/`.

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=Zj1zLT5zcGxpdCgifCJqb2luKHJlcGxhY2UocyxyIlxkIixkLT4iICJecGFyc2UoZCkpLCJ8IikifCIsIi8iKQoKQmFzZS5wcmludF9tYXRyaXgoU1RET1VULCBmKCI4LzgvOC84LzgvOC84LzgiKSkKcHJpbnRsbigiXG4iKQpCYXNlLnByaW50X21hdHJpeChTVERPVVQsIGYoInJuYnFrYm5yL3BwcHBwcHBwLzgvOC84LzgvUFBQUFBQUFAvUk5CUUtCTlIiKSkKcHJpbnRsbigiXG4iKQpCYXNlLnByaW50X21hdHJpeChTVERPVVQsIGYoInIxYmszci9wMnBCcE5wL240bjIvMXAxTlAyUC82UDEvM1A0L1AxUDFLMy9xNWIxIikp&input=)

Comment: Yay I inspired things :D

Comment: @QPaysTaxes You did indeed. Nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>50</s> 45 bytes

This was fun haha. Not only am I a noob in Retina,  but also in regex in general... This can probably be golfed a *lot*, so I'll do some more research.

Code:

```
8
44
7
34
6
42
5
 4
4
22
3
 2
2
  
1
 
/
¶

|
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=OAo0NAo3CjM0CjYKNDIKNQogNAo0CjIyCjMKIDIKMgogIAoxCiAKLwrCtgoKfA&input=cm5icWtibnIvcHBwcHBwcHAvOC84LzgvOC9QUFBQUFBQUC9STkJRS0JOUg)

Comment: Try using the `$*` functionality :)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

Code:

```
9GNNð×:}S'|ý"|ÿ|"'/¶:
```

Also 21 bytes: `'|¹9GNNð×:}S'|«JJ'/¶:`.

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=OUdOTsOww5c6fVMnfMO9InzDv3wiJy_Ctjo&input=cm5icWtibnIvcHBwcHBwcHAvOC84LzgvOC9QUFBQUFBQUC9STkJRS0JOUg).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.5, 112 bytes:

```
def r(o):print(''.join(['| '*8if h=='8'else'| '*int(h)if h.isdigit()else'|\n'if h=='/'else'|'+h for h in o])+'|')
```

[Try it online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/Vwuk9S)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>69</s> <s>67</s> 62 bytes

```
s=>[,...s.replace(/[/-8]/g,c=>+c?' '.repeat(c):`
`),,].join`|`
```

The extra commas create empty values in the outer split which creates the beginning and ending `|` characters. You need two trailing commas because trailing commas are optional at the end of lists, so the first one is still part of the previous item.

Edit: Saved 5 bytes thanks to @user81655.

Comment: Would `/[\d/]/g,c=>+c?\` \`.repeat(c):\`\n\`` work?

Comment: @user81655 Thanks, but I didn't like your emoticon, so I replaced it with an annoyed face with glasses.

Answer (score 2):

### R (out of competition)

Sorry if it's not appropriate to post this, but I thought it was cool that I just happened to have a function lying around that actually works for this question without editing! It prints unicode output rather than ascii, though. I can't remember quite why I wrote it, but it wasn't to answer a challenge.

```R
function(x){
# x = FEN position, a string
# can be split with / or ,
# example: forsythe("rnbqkbnr/pp1ppppp/8/2p5/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R")

allowed <- c(paste(1:64), 
c("k", "q", "r", "b", "n", "p", "K", "Q", "R", "B", "N", "P"))
chars <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
chars <- chars[-which(!(chars %in% allowed))]
out <- c()
for (i in 1:length(chars)){
  if (chars[i] %in% paste(1:64)){
    out <- c(out, rep(" ", as.numeric(chars[i])))
  }
  else{
    out <- c(out, chars[i])
  }
}
if (length(out) < 64) out <- c(out, rep(" ", 64-length(out)))

pieces <- strsplit("KQRBNPkqrbnp", "")[[1]]
unicode <- c("\u2654", "\u2655", "\u2656", 
"\u2657", "\u2658", "\u2659", "\u265A", "\u265B", 
"\u265C", "\u265D", "\u265E", "\u265F")

for (i in 1:64){
  if (out[i] %in% pieces){
    out[i] <- unicode[which(pieces==out[i])]
  }
  else{
  }
}
out <- matrix(out, nc=8, byrow=T)
#print(out)

plot(0, xlim=c(0, 8), ylim=c(0, 8), type="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n",
xlab="", ylab="")
for (i in 0:7){ for (j in 0:7){ rect(i, j, i+1, j+1,
col=ifelse(((i+j) %% 2) == 0, grey(0.95), "white"), border=F) }}

for (i in 0:7){ for (j in 0:7){
  text(i+0.5, j+0.5, out[8-j, i+1], cex=2)  
}}

axis(1, labels=letters[1:8], at=1:8 - 0.5, tick=F)
axis(2, labels=paste(1:8), at=1:8-0.5, las=2, tick=F)

}
```

Comment: The rules outlined in our [help center](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) state that all solutions to challenges must be a serious contender for the winning criteria in use. For code golf, this means that all answers must be golfed.

Comment: Technically, it is golfed. Just not very well.

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 28 bytes

```
RΜGi'/dΆγ'|RGρH«\d»d*♣PHEγγS
```

Replace `♣` with the character `\x05`, or [try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Us6cR2knL2TOhs6zJ3xSR8-BSMKrXGTCu2QqBVBIRc6zzrNT&input=cjFiazNyL3AycEJwTnAvbjRuMi8xcDFOUDJQLzZQMS8zUDQvUDFQMUszL3E1YjE)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 252 bytes

```c
i=-1,j,s=1,x;C(char*n){while(n[++i])s+=isdigit(n[i])?n[i]*2+1:2;char*m=(char*)malloc(s);for(i=j=-1;n[++i]&(m[++j]='|');)if(n[i]=='/')m[++j]='\n';else if(isdigit(n[i]))for(x=n[i]-'0';x;--x&&(m[++j]='|'))m[++j]=' ';else m[++j]=n[i];m[++j]='\0';return m;}
```

**Detailed** [*try online*](http://ideone.com/t76YtP)

```c
// input-string, input-string-size
char* C(char*n)
{
    int i=-1,j,s=1,x;

    // figure out required grid size
    while(n[++i])s+=isdigit(n[i])?n[i]*2+1:2;
    char*m=(char*)malloc(s);

    i=j=-1;
    while(n[++i]) // while not end of string
    {
        m[++j]='|'; // seperator

        if (n[i]=='/') // end of row
            m[++j]='\n';
        else if (isdigit(n[i])) // fill spaces
            for(x=n[i]-'0';x;--x&&(m[++j]='|')) m[++j]=' ';
        else
            m[++j]=n[i]; // single literals
    }

    m[++j]='|';
    m[++j]='\0';
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 110 Bytes

```
p '/'="\n"
p c|'1'<=c&&c<='8'=replicate(read[c])' '
p c=[c]
main=getLine>>=putStrLn.('|':).(>>=(:"|")).(>>=p)
```

### Ungolfed:

```
p c | c=='/'           = "\n"
    | '1'<=c && c<='8' = replicate (read [c]) ' '
    | otherwise        = [c]
addPipes string = "|" ++ concatMap (\c -> [c] ++ "|") string
main = getLine >>= putStrLn . addPipes . concatMap p
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (FireFox 30+), 61

Using array comprehension that is not standard EcmaScript anymore

```js
f=>'|'+[for(c of f)+c?' |'.repeat(c):c<'A'?`
|`:c+'|'].join``
```

**Test**

```js
F=f=>'|'+[for(c of f)+c?' |'.repeat(c):c<'A'?`\n|`:c+'|'].join``

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

;['8/8/8/8/8/8/8/8','rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR',
'r1bk3r/p2pBpNp/n4n2/1p1NP2P/6P1/3P4/P1P1K3/q5b1']
.forEach(t=>console.log(F(t)+'\n'))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 84 bytes

```
lambda a:"".join(c*c.isalpha()or"\n"*(c=="/")or" "*int(c)for c in a).replace("","|")
```

Explanation:

```
        c*c.isalpha()                                                       - if c is alphabetical, use c
                       "\n"*(c=="/")                                        - if it's "|", replace it with a newline
                                      " "*int(c)                            - else its an int.
"".join(                                                  ).replace("","|") - interweave "|" between the chars
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 106 Bytes

```lua
print("|"..(...):gsub(".",function(c)return c:find("%d")and(" |"):rep(c)or c=="/"and"\n|"or c.."|"end),'')
```

#### Ungolfed

```lua
print("|"..                   -- prepend | to the following string
  (...):gsub(".",function(c)  -- iterate over each character in the argument
    return                    -- replaces in the argument
           c:find("%d")       -- if c is a number
             and(" |"):rep(c) --   replace by " |"*c
           or c=="/"          -- elseif c is a slash
             and"\n|"         -- replace by "\n|"
           or c.."|"          -- else (case letter)replace by c
  end)                        -- return the modified string
,'')                          -- add an empty parameter to print
                              -- it suppresses the second output of gsub
```

Comment: `print((...):gsub(".",function(c)return(c:find("%d")and("| "):rep(c)or c=="/"and"|\n"or"|"..c)end).."|")`

Comment: `print((...):gsub("%d",function(c)return("| "):rep(c)end):gsub("/","|\n"):gsub("([^%d%s|])","|%1").."|")` for the same byte-count.

Comment: `print((...):gsub("%d",function(c)return("| "):rep(c)end):gsub("([^%d |])","|%1"):gsub("/","\n").."|")` is 101 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, 64 bytes

```
<v?(0:i
r\
"<o-*=@"%/":   v?*(@)@":/"::;?(0:o"|
 ^~?="0":-1o" "<
```

4 wasted bytes due to alignment issues, not sure how to golf them out though. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>190</s> 184 bytes

```
String Z(int c){String m="";if(c==47)m+="|\n";else if(c>57)m+="|"+c;else while(c-->48)m+="| ";return m;}String C(String n){String m="";for(char x:n.toCharArray())m+=Z(x);return m+"|";}
```

**Detailed** [*try online*](http://ideone.com/Lc36JE)

```
public static String Z(char c)
{
    String m="";
    if(c=='/')m+="|\n";
    else if(c>'9')m+="|"+c;
    else while(c-->'0')m+="| ";
    return m;
}

public static String C(String n)
{
    String m="";
    for(char x:n.toCharArray())m+=Z(x);
    return m+"|";
}
```

Comment: You can save a couple of bytes be using integers instead of char literals in the comparisons

Comment: @Blue notes taken

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, <s>25</s> 20 bytes

```
FD~u{RIbd*(s\/n:k\|:
```

Explanation:

```
F         (          -    for char in input:
 D~u{RI              -     if char in '0123456789': 
       bd*           -      char = " "*int(char)
           s         -   sum(^)
            \/n:     -  ^.replace("/","\n")
                k\|: - ^.replace("", "|")
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=FD%7Eu%7BRIbd%2a%28s%5C%2Fn%3Ak%5C%7C%3A&input=r1bk3r%2Fp2pBpNp%2Fn4n2%2F1p1NP2P%2F6P1%2F3P4%2FP1P1K3%2Fq5b1)

Answer (score 0):

## brev, 89 bytes

```
(fn(print(strse x'num(->(m 0)string->number(make-string #\ ))"."(c conc "|")"/""\n")"|"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r\dÈ°çÃrP'| q'/
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVI&code=clxkyLDnw3JQJ3wgcScv&input=InIxYmszci9wMnBCcE5wL240bjIvMXAxTlAyUC82UDEvM1A0L1AxUDFLMy9xNWIxIg)

```
r\dÈ°çÃrP'| q'/     :Implicit input of string U
r                   :Replace
 \d                 :  Regex /[0-9]/g
   È                :  Pass each match through a function
    °               :    Postfix increment (to convert from string to integer)
     ç              :    Repeat a space that many time
      Ã             :End replace
       r            :Replace
        P           :  Empty string
         '|         :  With "|"
            q'/     :Split on "/"
                    :Implicit output, joined with newlines
```